# Jquery multilevel accordion using UL

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to create a multilevel accordion using nested unordered list.

What I am trying to accomplish:

- Show only the "active" ul (other
  remain hidden)
- When there is a nested ul - toggle
  only the nested ul (2222 -> 2.1)

Full code here: http://pastie.org/852421

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul.menu li ul').hide();

    $('ul.menu li a').click(function(e){

        $('ul.menu li a').each(function(i){
            if($(this).next().is("ul") && $(this).next().is(":visible")){
                $(this).next().slideUp("fast");
            }
        });

        var e = $(e.target);                

        if(e.next().is("ul") && e.next().is(":visible")){
            e.next().slideUp("fast");
            } else {
            e.next().slideDown("fast");
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">11111</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="one">1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="one">1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">22222</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2.1+ (problem)</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">2.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2.2.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">33333</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add class `.active` to active `li` and then call with jQuery:

```
$("ul:has(li.active)").slideDown();
```

simple ;]

Edit:
also, I previously used following:

```
$(rootparent+' ul').hide();
$(rootparent+' ul:has(li#active)').show();
$(rootparent+">li:has(a[href*='"+activepage+"'])>ul").show();
```

(`rootparent` is topmost `ul`, `activepage` is active `URI`)

Comment: and don't be so quick with -1